# In the equation $R = R_0 [1+αt(∆T)]$ is $R_0$ the resistance only at 0K/0°C?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, conventions

For example, we're asked to find the resistance at a temperature 20°C, we know that the resistance at 10°C is 5 ohm, and we know the value of the temperature coefficient of resistance. Can we put Ro as 5 ohm and proceed with the equation or will two different equations need to be created?

Comment: Usually $R_0$ is the resistance at $0\,\rm ^\circ C$ which you can find by using the resistance at $10\,\rm ^\circ C$.

Comment: So we'll get different results if we keep Ro as 5 ohm and ∆T=(20°C- 10°C)?

Comment: Try it and see what you get using the two different methods.

Comment: I just did, and they're different answers. Thank you! Can you help me understand why they're different answers?

Comment: You are approximating the resistance against temperature to a straight line graph.  
The equation of the straight line is defined by one point $(R_0\,\Omega,0^\circ \rm C)$ and the gradient of the line $\alpha$.

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks!